# How to modified the background of selected gridviewitem in gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8

In windows8, when we selected an item in gridview, the default background color is purple, how to change the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link on msdn might help you with your problem. It sounds similar based on the tags you chose: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winappswithcsharp/thread/98e6d866-9c54-4ee2-a9e8-767c74363b13

Comment: Hi, yes, I have read this link before, but when my mouse over the item, the color still purple

Comment: You may want to change the Base color for the SelectionBackground element in the States panel (at the top) - it sounds like you may have changed only the "Normal" state so the PointerOver, PointerOverPressed, etc. states will retain the original base color