# How to change the color of the gridviewitem when mouse over on it in windows8

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I've created a gridview, when mouse goes over on it, the background color changes to purple, how can I stop this color change behaviour?

Comment: http://steptodotnet.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-change-gridview-row-color-on.html

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks for your reply, could you please confirm the link? I couldn't open it.

Comment: @James link works for me

Comment: but the link is for ASP.net, question seems to refer to WinRT-XAML

Comment: this seems like a dupe of your [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071024/how-to-modified-the-background-of-selected-gridviewitem-in-gridview) to which I responded - did that suggestion not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF it is straightforward. You need to override [SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1278299/649524).

In Windows 8 Modern UI apps, this is little complex. It involves overriding the control template and changes in visual states using [visual state manager](http://www.markermetro.com/2011/11/technical/windows-8-metro-style-apps-layout-and-orientation-management-with-xaml/). Solution is provided in this [msdn forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/winappswithcsharp/thread/3faadbc2-4ec8-4235-959c-2c0bb4701814).